# Will commenters be notified when copy of shared file is made

Tags: google-docs

If a make a copy (`File` / `Make a copy`) of a Google Docs file that I own and that is shared with commenters, will those receive a notification (email) of that event and will the copy also have them as commenters?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be certain, but I use Google Docs a lot and have never had an email when something has been duplicated by a colleague. However, I do tend to have notifications turned off. I also know that you can share or not share a duplicated document - see screenshot. Hope that helps, a bit.
[image: Share a duplicated Google Doc]

Comment: I was about to upvote your answer. But since somebody chose to downvote this innocent question, I'm not really in the mood right now :) Thx anyway.